# Prove that $A$ is a singular matrix if and only if zero is an eigenvalue (of $A$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am completely confused about this one. I know that a singular matrix is a matrix that does not have an inverse

I also know that I can find the eigenvalues of a matrix by finding the determinant of $A - yI$ so i guess i have to solve $A-0I$ which is just equal to $A$. But I dont think this tells me anything...

But that's about all i know, any help will be appreciated

Comment: thank you, i didn't see that post. You can delete this post if you want

Comment: @Soon_to_be_code_master You should be able to delete it yourself.